# How can decorators implement new behaviour?

Tags: decorator

I am trying to teach myself design patterns. I was reading about the `Decorator` pattern, and there's one thing that I can't quite get. Here is an example found on wikipedia:[image: Example]
Let's say I want to implement a window that can scroll both horizontally and vertically, I would do this:
`Window win=new Window();
win=new HorizontalScrollBarDecorator(win);
win=new VerticalScrollBarDecorator(win);`

Since `win` is a reference of type `Window`, I can call neither `drawHorizontalScrollBar()` nor `drawVerticalScrollBar()` (apart from the code in the concrete decorator itself), and of course it would not make sense to change the reference type.
So, how can I "add new behaviour" (I.E. implement new methods) with decoration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I think I got it:
Through decoration you can't "add new behaviour" as I had interpreted it (`drawHorizontalScrollBar()` is not visible from outside the `HorizontalScrollBarDecorator` class, which means it's probably called by its `draw()` method), BUT you can extend methods of the base class.
It's like extending the base class, overriding the `draw()` method and then calling `super.draw();`, with the difference that you can apply multiple `decorators`, but you can't inherit from multiple classes.

Comment: Feel free to confirm/add new details/edit the answer, it's kind of a wild guess